# Performance implications of adding a new library in react

Tags: reactjs, performance, frontend, react-flow

I am trying to build a flowchart component, and I am trying to decide if I should build it from scratch with svgs or use an existing library like react flow.

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

What are the performance implications of adding another package to an existing app bundle, and how can I measure that?

How do vulnerabilities in npm packages affect one's decision to use a library or not?

What testing implications are there for each approach?

Answer (score 1):

Building from scratch would probably take longer and might even have worse performance if your code is sloppy. Popular libraries are usually well put together and optimized for performance already. Customizability might be something you're looking for but most libraries allow for that nowadays too. Vulnerabilities in npm packages can be concerning if they're severe or critical, but if you're just testing things, it should be fine. Unless you're building a mass scale application where custom specifications are necessary, I think you'd be better off using libraries.